# Flux control of transformer

Tags: transformer, magnetic-flux

Can the flux (not flux density) of a transformer be controlled so as to achieve constant voltage output with varied loads? For example, increasing the flux slightly when the load is high.

Comment: A feedback loop and tap changer. Done in most commercial distribution transformers.

Comment: A tap changer needs to be mechanically operated. Is it possible to make use of some electronic circuits to vary the flux so as to change the voltage

Comment: Isn't this basically how every isolated smps works?

Comment: Sure. Thyristor tap changer.

Comment: I believe a mag amp will do this.

Comment: What would happen if I apply a voltage (in the same phase as primary) to a tertiary winding wound over the transformer core? Would the mutual flux change or would the primary draw a different value of current so as to oppose the change in flux? (In short, would this tertiary winding act similar to the primary winding (injecting flux) or would it act similar to secondary winding (load for primary))

Comment: @winny Sorry that I didn't mention earlier that I want to change the flux (or voltage) in a smooth fashion. As for thyristor tap changer, it only switches between discrete values of windings and hence the arcing problem persists. Is flux control possible in the way I have written about above?

Comment: Then mag amp or SMPS with duty-cycle control to produce constant Vt product.

Comment: @winny Can you please elaborate a bit? I have **very** little idea about SMPS as I haven't been taught power electronics yet!

Comment: Google a schematic for almost any isolated SMPS. Flux will be proportional to Vt product and with variying input voltage, you can adjust the duty cycle of the switch(es) to compensate for that, producing constant flux. Non the less, it all sounds like an XY problem. Generating constant voltage output is your A1 task in any SMPS or linear design and keeping the flux constant isn't a constrain.